# Converting TIF from RGB to Grayscale

Tags: python, image-processing

So I am trying to convert RGB TIF file to grayscale. This is the Python code

```
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tifffile as tfl

def rgb2gray(rgb):
    return np.dot(rgb[...,:3], [0.2989, 0.587, 0.114])

imName = 'three_band/6120_2_0.tif'
im_rgb=tfl.imread(imName).transpose([1,2,0])
gray = rgb2gray(im_rgb)
plt.imshow(gray)
```

But when I try to view it using pyplot, I get a blue image like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oezL7.png)

Can anyone point to what's wrong with my code?
Thanks.

Comment: This is a simple case of wrong order of values of the color. TFL is using RBG instead of RGB to store the values. As a result you are adding more weight to blue when you intend to add it to green.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya does it mean that changing weights in rbg2grey would help?

Comment: Yes, you would have to swap the second and third weights - np.dot(rgb[...,:3], [0.289, 0.114, 0.587])

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya nope, didn't work, just tried that

Comment: I see the problem now. What are you doing with the gray value? Realize that gray(dot) is a single number and not an rgb pair. Could you try passing [gray, gray, gray] to matplotlib?

Comment: A grayscale image is a colored image with R=G=B. What you are doing I think is setting B to the correct value but R and G are remaining 0.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya According to the gray.shape, it actually is a (3348, 3403) matrix. Its minimum number is 438.18899999999996, and maximum is 1096.7525000000001. I was trying to rescale it and nothing really works. it all comes out blue.

Comment: Do you mind sharing the entire code here? Specifically what you are doing after you call rgb2gray(im_rgb).

Comment: I added one line. I am just trying to output the code after rgb2gray.

Comment: So the matplotlib.imshow function expects an array of dimension (width x height x 3) but you are only passing (width x height)

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya but if it is gray scale, it should be (n x m x 1) right? which is the same as (n x m)?

Comment: Can you try adding gray = np.array([gray, gray, gray]).transpose([2,0,1]) and then pass it to imshow?

Comment: Yes grayscale images are m x n x 1. But in that case you have to tell imshow that this is a gray scale image. This can be done by passing a parameter plt.imshow(gray, cmap = plt.get_cmap('gray')). But if you want to represent it as an RGB image just repeat the gray value three times.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya It gives an error "Invalid dimensions for image data".

Comment: Can you print and check gray.shape?

Comment: (3348, 3403) is the result of shape.

Comment: I meant after the transpose. Anyway, I tested it on my machine and realized that the argument to transpose was incorrect. The correct one would be gray = np.array([gray, gray, gray]).transpose([1,2,0])

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya Thank you very much, I think this worked, thank you!